# What is the best design pattern for a node - link diagram in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, graph, nodes, diagram

What is the best design pattern for a node - link diagram in Java?

The model should be seperable from the graphical representation.
There are several types of nodes.
There are rules as to which nodes can connect to other nodes and how many.
Java 1.7

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. SO is not a code delivery service.

Comment: Oh I don't want any code, I would like to know the best type of design pattern for this or literature on it.

Comment: The current implementation is complex so would rather not put it up. I need a more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use literature of graph in data structures.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

Then there are famous algorithms you can implement. Depends on what you want to do one of the depth first and breadth first algorithms are more appropriate for you
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate your model from the view, you can use the MVC pattern. For the problem of the nodes, you need to study about graph data structures.

To have multiple types of nodes you can take a look at the composite pattern, which work like the DOM in HTML (you have parents and childrens). You can adapt it to have a graph but take car if you want to explore it, you can have some cyclic way (you have to look at the graph exploration algorithms).